# Different URL formats return different datatypes from the same API using Pythons requests.get

Tags: python, python-requests

Why do these two URL formats return different datatypes, when they all pull data from the same API?

This returns a nested dictionary, which is the correct type:

```
user = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/{}'.format(1)).json()
```

output:

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Leanne Graham',
  'username': 'Bret',
  'email': 'Sincere@april.biz',
  'address': {
    'street': 'Kulas Light',
    'suite': 'Apt. 556',
    'city': 'Gwenborough',
    'zipcode': '92998-3874',
    'geo': {
      'lat': '-37.3159',
      'lng': '81.1496'
    }
  },
  'phone': '1-770-736-8031 x56442',
  'website': 'hildegard.org',
  'company': {
    'name': 'Romaguera-Crona',
    'catchPhrase': 'Multi-layered client-server neural-net',
    'bs': 'harness real-time e-markets'
  }
}
```

While this returns a list of dictionaries:

```
user = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id={}'.format(1)).json()
```

output:

```
[{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Leanne Graham',
  'username': 'Bret',
  'email': 'Sincere@april.biz',
  'address': {
    'street': 'Kulas Light',
    'suite': 'Apt. 556',
    'city': 'Gwenborough',
    'zipcode': '92998-3874',
    'geo': {
      'lat': '-37.3159',
      'lng': '81.1496'
    }
  },
  'phone': '1-770-736-8031 x56442',
  'website': 'hildegard.org',
  'company': {
    'name': 'Romaguera-Crona',
    'catchPhrase': 'Multi-layered client-server neural-net',
    'bs': 'harness real-time e-markets'
  }
}]
```

Please note the different url formats

This is a sample of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import requests
if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id={}'.format(1)).json()
    print(user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python or `requests.get` and little to do with URL formats. It's the service that decides how to parse that URL and how to map its elements.

- In the first case `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1` is treated as a single resource identifier (which it is) so the service returns a single object serialized as JSON. In JavaScript objects *are* dictionaries. What you posted is a single object, not nested dictionaries
- In the second case, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id=1`it treats the URL as a query on the `Users` resource with a filter `id=1` so it returns an array of objects, even though there's only a single matching object.

[JSONPlaceholder's docs](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) explain that this syntax is used for filtering:

> **Filtering resources**
>
> Basic filtering is supported through query parameters.

Another service could decide that since `id` is a key, it should return a single object instead of an array. Or it could use a different query string, using eg `filter` to explicitly specify filter parameters

There's no standard for either case. While it's a common convention especially in REST-like APIs to include an object's ID in the URL path, there's no single standard or even convention for queries. Each service uses its own format.

GraphQL (from Facebook) and OData (from Microsoft) are two common query and manipulation protocols. They're a *lot* more complex than the very simple filtering used by JSONPlaceholder though

Answer (score 2):

The first end point you are requesting a specific user i.e. id 1 which is a single resource object:

```
user = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id={}'.format(1)).json()
```

The second end point is for returning multiple users hence why it's returned as a list of objects.

```
user = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id={}'.format(1)).json()
```

This endpoint and query string combination offers little value using a user id like this as it would only return a single user.

An API end point like this would normally be used to filter a list of matched users for example which users were created after a particular date.